# How do I assign a variable to LookupRows results?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup

Basically, I want to print out the results from LookupRow, I have tried quite a few different things but to no avail. For example it would find all of the email addresses (maximum 4), that have the country of Italy, and I want to assign a variable to each email address to then be inserted as part of separate entries into a data extension.

```
%%[
set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* all */
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("Extranet_Config",@numRowsToReturn,"EmailAddress Desc","SalesRegion",@Country)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

    for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

       var @Owner
       set @row = row(@rows,@i)
       set @Owner = field(@row,"EmailAddress")

       if @i == 1 then
          outputline(concat("<p>"))
       endif 

       ]%%

       %%=v(@Owner)=%%

       %%[ 

       if @i == @rowcount then
          outputline(concat("</p>"))
       endif

    next @i 
]%%

%%[ else ]%%

%%[ endif ]%%

]%%


<p>Here = %%=v(@Owner)=%%</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this code is executed on a Landing/Microsite Page.  If that's the case, you could do it something like this:

```
%%[

/* assuming @country is set prior */
set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* all */
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("Extranet_Config",@numRowsToReturn,"EmailAddress Desc","SalesRegion",@Country)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

outputline(concat("<br>@country: ",@country))
outputline(concat("<br>@rowCount: ",@rowCount))

if @rowCount > 0 then

    /* enforce max number of rows to list */
    if @rowCount > 4 then
      set @rowCount = 4
    endif

    for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

       var @OwnerEmailAddress
       set @row = row(@rows,@i)
       set @OwnerEmailAddress = field(@row,"EmailAddress")

       /* OWNERDATAEXTENSION DE has EmailAddress (EmailAddress), InsertedDate (Date) columns */
       upsertData("OWNERDATAEXTENSION",1,"EmailAddress",@ownerEmailAddress,"InsertedDate", now())

       if @i == 1 then
          outputline(concat("<p>"))
       endif 

       outputline(concat("<br>Adding row to OWNERDATAEXTENSION for: ",@@OwnerEmailAddress))

       if @i == @rowcount then
          outputline(concat("</p>"))
       endif

    next @i 
else
  outputline(concat("<br>No Extranet_Config rows found"))
endif 

]%%
```